# Making an output of frends names instead of IDs

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can somebody help me with this, i m new to javaScript and i m stuck at this point.I made an output of certain object within my array ,that output is writing a persons values, within that object(Osoba) there is an array of his friends and all values inside are IDs of each person, http://prntscr.com/i9m2ti how can i make that ID of a friend array ( within the object ) to be a first name and surname of that person which id is in array and when i want to output a certain object so there will be friends[ their names instead of IDs], can someone write me down how can i do that. Thanks for understanding.

```
class Osoba{
constructor(id,firstName,surname,age,gender,friends){
    this._id = id ;
    this._firstName = firstName;
    this._surname = surname;
    this._age = age;
    this._gender = gender;
    this._friends = friends;
    }

    get id() {
        return this._id;
    }
    set id(id){
        this._id = id;
    }
    get firstName() {
        return this._firstName;
    }
    set firstName(firstName){
        this._firstName = firstName;
    }
    get surname() {
        return this._surname;
    }
    set surname(surname){
        this._surname = surname;
    }
    get age() {
        return this._age;
    }
    set age(age){
        this._age = age;
    }

    get gender() {
        return this._gender;
    }
    set gender(gender){
        this._gender = gender;
    }

    get friends() {
        return this._friends;
    }
    set friends(friends){
        this._friends = friends;
    }

}

var osobe = [];  // my array


   $(function() {

   $.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Steffzz/damnz/master/
  data.json' , function(data) 
    {
          var json = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));

        for(person of json)
        {

            var id = person['id']  ;
            var firstName = person['firstName'] ;
            var surname = person['surname'] ;
            var age = person['age'] ;
            var gender= person['gender'] ;
            var friends = person['friends'] ;

            var x = new Osoba(id,firstName,surname,age,gender,friends); 
            osobe.push(x); //filling array with objects and their values
        }     
        console.log(osobe);
       document.write(JSON.stringify(osobe[0])) //output of a certain object
      }) 
 });
```

Comment: please write the non-code part of your quest better. It is quite hard to understand what you actually want to do, and what it is you are actually asking.

Comment: okay i did, try now, thanks

Comment: I updated the answer, if i undestood the question correctly you only need to change 1 line of code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming json is an array and contains all people you can map over friends array and find the person with that id: `person['friends'].map(` and `json.find(function(person){person.id===friendId});`.

Then return an object containing that person's first and last name:

```
console.log("json is:",JSON.stringify(json,undefined,3));
var friends = person['friends'].map(
  function(friendId){
    console.log("friendID is:",friendId);
    var friend = json.find(function(person){return person.id===friendId;});
    console.log("friend is:",JSON.stringify(friend,undefined,2));
    return {
      firstName:friend.firstName,
      surname:friend.surname
    }
  }
);
```

Now if that "does not work" could you please specify the output of the logs, any errors and expected results versus actual results?

**UPDATE FULL CODE**

Since the `json` is all your data you can pass that into your Osoba constructor. The friends getter will use the data to create an array Osaba items that will have data and friends that will create an array of Osaba ...

```
class Osoba {
  constructor(id, firstName, surname, age, gender, friends, data) {//added data
    this._id = id;
    this._firstName = firstName;
    this._surname = surname;
    this._age = age;
    this._gender = gender;
    this._friends = friends;
    this._data = data;//data has all the people
  }

  get id() {
    return this._id;
  }
  set id(id) {
    this._id = id;
  }
  get firstName() {
    return this._firstName;
  }
  set firstName(firstName) {
    this._firstName = firstName;
  }
  get surname() {
    return this._surname;
  }
  set surname(surname) {
    this._surname = surname;
  }
  get age() {
    return this._age;
  }
  set age(age) {
    this._age = age;
  }

  get gender() {
    return this._gender;
  }
  set gender(gender) {
    this._gender = gender;
  }
  //modified friends getter returning an array of Osoba items
  get friends() {
    var me = this;
    return this._friends.map(
      function (friendId) {
        var friend = me._data.find(function (person) { return person.id === friendId; });
        return new Osoba(
          friend.id,
          friend.firstName,
          friend.surname,
          friend.age,
          friend.gender,
          friend.friends,
          me._data
        );
      }
    );
  }

  set friends(friends) {
    this._friends = friends;
  }

}
$.getJSON('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Steffzz/damnz/master/data.json')
  .then(
  json => {
    var people = json.map(
      person =>
        new Osoba(
          person.id,
          person.firstName,
          person.surname,
          person.age,
          person.gender,
          person.friends,
          json
        )
    );
    //you can keep getting friends now, because Osoba is
    //  creating new Osoba objects based on id's and data you pass in
    console.log(people[0].friends[0].friends[0].friends[0]);
  }
  );
```

Comment: @StefanSipic That's missing the `json is:` log. Please read carefully; `Assuming json is an array and contains all people` That assumes 1. json is an array (I guess it is because `map` works) 2. Any id in `friends` can be found in `json` having an `id` of `friendId`

Comment: is there a possible way to make a new atribute within the class which is empty array and to make a function to get IDs from friends array and to write them as firstname and surname from that ID inside empty array from class and to ouput that empty array with all this atributes in object

Comment: @StefanSipic Code should work but seems someone has a friend with id of `2` but that person does not exist in the `json` data. So you have someone with a friend that doesn't exist and trying to get a first and last name from a non existing person. Code is fine but data is not.

Comment: are you sure? check this link from the code https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Steffzz/damnz/master/data.json this is my json data

Comment: @StefanSipic Ah, I see: `var friend = json.find(function(person){person.id===friendId});` should be `var friend = json.find(function(person){return person.id===friendId;});` forgot to return `person.id===friendId`. Return statement is usually not needed in arrow functions bu since your script was classic JS I assumed you're not using ES for modern browsers or a bundler/transpiler. I updated the answer.

Comment: @StefanSipic Also [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Steffzz/damnz/master/%20data.json) in your code didn't work because you have a space in there.

Comment: yes i realized that but i had to do it so it can show it as a code, thanks its working, btw any idea how can i access friends of these friends?

Comment: i dont get it, can you be a bit more plainer, please, i m still new to this i m trying to understand everything, what is with the array that i made and filled it with for of loop? what should i change in my code its all messed up now :D

Comment: No you didnt understand me, i wanted to access the friends of the FRIEND ARRAY you know, like friends of these friends like to put array of their friends for each friend into friend array and to print it, any idea how can i do that

Comment: or somehow to make a new array where i will put these friends of friends for a certain object

Comment: @StefanSipic can you update your question and specify exactly what input you have and what output you expect?

Comment: Lets say like this {"_id":7,"_firstName":"Sarah","_surname":"Lane","_age":30,"_gender":"female","_friends":[{"firstName":"Ben","surname":"O'Carolan"},{"firstName":"Peter","surname":"Mac"},{"firstName":"Katy","surname":"Couch"},{"firstName":"Laura","surname":"Murphy"},{"firstName":"Susan","surname":"Downe"}]}  ( those are friends of an id 7 ) is it possible to make now to show friends of each value within friend array for example _friends":[{"firstName":"Ben","surname":"O'Carolan"} and now to catch id of ben and to show friends of ben

Comment: @StefanSipic you'll get a circular reference because person A has friend B who has friend A who has friend B ... Current code in answer basically has friends of friends of friends of friends of friends ... if you ask for it but I don't know for sure if you can parse it to JSON (JSON doesn't take circular references). `people[0].friends[0].friends[0].friends[0].friends[0].friends[0].friends[0].friends[0].friends[0].friends[0]...can go on forever`

Comment: i need something like loop within the loop that will go trough the object and array friends catch their id and for every id to go trough their friends list and to print that IDS ( just in format of first name and surname like that above for a normal objects )

Comment: @StefanSipic I'm not sure what you're on about, sorry. people is an array of Osoba (I didn't come up with that ridiculous name, you did). Each Osoba has friends that is an array of Osoba object that have firstName and surname. If you only want first and surname from the Osoba object you can do this: `people[0].friends.map(({firstName,surname})=>({firstName,surname}))`

Comment: how can i make an array in friends array in person object so there i can store friends of persons friends?

Comment: @StefanSipic A person.friends is already an array of Osabo objects.

Comment: and now i need to get friends of person.friends of osoba object

Comment: @StefanSipic `person.friends.map(friend=>friend.fiends)` be careful of circular reference B is friend of A is friend of B is friend of A ...

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you just want to use id for id, firstname, and lastname. so just pass id 3 times instead of firstname and lastname:

```
var x = new Osoba(id,id,id,age,gender,friends);
```

~~~~

Ok so what you want is actually that the id property within each friend object be the first and last name of the friend instead of an idea code. So it's basically just the opposite of what i suggested earlier. All you have to do is manipulate what you push to id. There's no obligation on it being the id from the json.

so in your case:

```
for(person of json){

        var id = person['firstName'] + "" + person['surname']; // line to change.
        var firstName = person['firstName'] ;
        var surname = person['surname'] ;
        var age = person['age'] ;
        var gender= person['gender'] ;
        var friends = person['friends'] ;

        var x = new Osoba(id,firstName,surname,age,gender,friends); 
        osobe.push(x); //filling array with objects and their values
    }
```

Comment: as i said there is an object PERSON and that person has array FRIENDS inside that object that represents ID of persons friends ( and that friends are in json file and their inex is ID ) so when i document.write it it gives me this https://prnt.sc/i9m2ti and instead of that FRIEND array where is [2] i want there to be a firstName and surname of that id 2

Comment: ahhhhh ok then i think @christoph has answered your question by now.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
var friends = person['friends'] ;
```

try

```
var friends = []; 
var friendIDs = person['friends'] ; //retrieve friendIDs

for(friendID of friendIDs) { //loop over friendIDs
  var friend = json[friendID]; //get friend dataset out of the json
  friends.push(friend['firstName']); // add friend dataset to friends array
}
```

I assume here that those friends are in that json aswell. and that the ids represent that index inside that array. if the indexes aren't those ids this won't work. feel free to comment if thats the case and i'll edit my answer.

Comment: yes that is true , ids represent their index, where should i put this loop and try it ?

Comment: replace var friends = person['friends'] ; with the code

Comment: i think i might have somehow to make some function within the class and there to swap their ids with their names and surnames and to put it in the loop

Comment: or just to make a new variable in the class that is empty array and than to try this loop you made

Comment: could you be more specific ? any errors ? and could you maybe give us a full output of your json array? its hard to help you without knowing what really is inside your data

Comment: Here is the link from the code https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Steffzz/damnz/master/data.json when i get an output of first person and the values of friend array within that object i want it to be first name and surname of that ID inside friend array

Comment: @StefanSipic id is definetely not index. Index of array is zero based and id start with 1. If the id is index+1 you can do: `var friend = json[friendID-1];`. Id's based on index in an array will give you a lot of headaches when you add or remove people.